# Constructing a subsequence for {cos(nr)}

Tags: functional-analysis, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

How can I prove that there exists a subsequence of $\{\cos(nr)\}_{n=1}^\infty $, where $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, that converges pointwise on $\mathbb{Q}$ to a real valued function?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any diagonal argument would do.

Comment: Do you know diagonal extraction argument?